# Android: getting data in edit text from server

Tags: android, json, httpclient, android-edittext

I am having three EditText

1. username
2. name
3. email

I want to fill up these EditText automatically once logged in by the user and I want these values from the server using `json`.
Can any one help me in doing this. I am a newbie to json parsing so please help

Comment: hey! you need to past some code snipest here..so we can get idea?

Comment: What have you done so far? Any posts or tutorials you've covered?

Comment: After parsing the json string,you'll get username,name & email as a string.set these values in the editext as edittext.settext(username); and same as for name and email.

Answer (score 1):

you have to implement the method on click to get the values of the EditText.

```
String username = youedittext.getText().toString();
String name = youedittext2.getText().toString();
String email = youedittext3.getText().toString();

DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    ArrayList<NameValuepair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
                    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                    nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mail", mail));
        HttpPost hpost = new HttpPost(url);
        hpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity());
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(hpost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        String result = sb.toString();

        JSONObject jobject = new JSONObject(result);
                    //Here you have to read the JSONObject it's very easy

                Log.i("Content:",jobject.toString());
```

Comment: I think this user need to fill data into edittext...so your code is not full you need to put those values into edittext, or can i do it for you?......like this :   username.setText(username); please edit your answer

Comment: hey i am getting the error on `return jobject` line..it is saying to change the return type to JSONObject.

Comment: can you please tell how to do this using `httpget` ??

Comment: @MarcOrtiz Please let him do _his job_.